# Best book to learn Affine Geometry?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, big-list, affine-geometry

I'm going to learn Affine plane as well as affine Geometry. Unfortunately, my text book (not in English) is not good at all, so please recommend some book you think it's good for self-learning (and also for advanced research). For every book,can you please give me details what do you think about that book and whom that book is appropriate for?

I skimmed through my book, what I'm going to learn is Affine space, affine map,affine group, superplane, barycenter...

Hope some one can help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There are some links at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry maybe that is a good point to start, GOOD LUCK

Comment: I try to see all the links in wiki, but unfortunately, some links are too advanced, and the others are too vague. I try to find some classic textbooks about this topic. Can you give me more hints?Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently reading Brannan's [*Geometry*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107647835), and it has a very nice introductory chapter into Affine Geometry. As a book in itself, I would also recommend it.